# Ruby: RSpec fails when try to test STDERR output

Tags: ruby, error-handling, rspec, stderr, argv

I have `collector.rb` file with something like this:

```
class Collector
  def initialize(input)
    raise ArgumentError, 'must be positive integer' unless input.to_i.positive?
  end
  # more code...
end

begin
  Collector.new(*ARGV).do_something
rescue ArgumentError => e
  warn e.message
end
```

So when I do `$ ruby collector.rb` in terminal, I get `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` as expected [from Ruby docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html)

In my test file I have:

```
require 'rspec'
require './collector'

RSpec.describe Collector do
  let(:exec) { File.expand_path('../collector.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__)) }

  describe 'input in console' do
    context 'when wrong number of arguments' do
      specify { expect {`ruby #{exec} `}.to output('wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)').to_stderr }
    end
  end
end
```

At the moment my test is failing as it cannot detect any output to `STDERR` although I'm following recommendation [from here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher#output-to-stderr-matcher)
**What am I doing wrong here, please?** I'd be happy for any hint how to fix my code.

Comment: You did not write for which line you get the error message, but if you really run the program by `ruby collector.rb`, `ARGV` will be empty and `Collector::initialize` is called with zero arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backquotes in ruby run a command in a separate process. When you test `to_output...to_stderr` you test it on the parent process (RSpec), not the child process (ruby).

In order to test child process stderr, you can use [`Open3.popen3`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) that gives you access to process stderr.

Try sth like this (not tested):

```
require 'open3'

specify do
  Open3.popen3("ruby #{exec}") do |_stdin, _stdout, stderr|
    expect(stderr.read.strip).to eq('wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)')
  end
end
```